# Laravel: removing "api" prefix from a single route

Tags: laravel

I need to remove a prefix "api" to only one of the routes in api folder in Laravel project. Is this possible?  I know that it works for all the routes by using mapApiRoutes function but this does not work for just one route.

Comment: a hacky solution would be to create a new file and register it in routeserviceprovider

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the Laravel [Sub-Domain Routing](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing) in order to create a single route using your application url + the path that you want to create.

```
Route::domain(config('app.url') . '/path')->group(function () {
    Route::get('path/', function () {
        // your code...
    });
});
```